# Resizing of Label in AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX `Label` inside an `AnchorPane`, which is contained in a `VBox`. This one is in a `ScrollPane`. I want the text to wrap and to automatically adapt to the width of the window.

Here is a simplified example of my code:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(MainApp.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane();
        root.setFitToWidth(true);

        VBox vbx = new VBox();
        vbx.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        vbx.setSpacing(20);
        root.setContent(vbx);

        Label lbl = new Label(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, " +
                "sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore " + 
                "magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et " +
                "accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.");
        lbl.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
        lbl.setWrapText(true);

        AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();
        ap.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
        ap.getChildren().add(lbl);
        vbx.getChildren().add(ap);

        lbl.maxWidthProperty().bind(ap.widthProperty());
        lbl.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);

        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(lbl, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(lbl, 0.0);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**The Problem is**: When I start the program, the `Label` is much higher than the available height and the text is centered vertically inside. When I resize the width of the window, the text jumps to the top and its height is reduced to the correct size. But the `VBox` remains very large.

What do I have to change, that the text is initially in the correct position (at the top) without having to resize the window and how to make the VBox not larger than necessary?

**Please note**: The `AnchorPane` is there for some reasons that would take to long to explain, so I cannot remove it. Also I cannot change the `Label` to `Text` because it must remain at least anything derived from `Region`

Comment: worksforme (in fx10, didn't check other versions)

Comment: I tested in FX10 now but I still got the same problem.

Comment: Is the `VBox` also there for some reasons that would take to long to explain?

Comment: No, the `VBox` can be changed, removed, replaced. etc. I just need it to layout multiple of these labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should **not** add a `VBox` as the root node in a `ScrollPane`. I am saying this because `SceneBuilder` would **not** let me do it. In this example, I make the root node an `AnchorPane`. Then I add the `VBox` and its children. I bind the `Label's` width to the `Stage`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(MainApp.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        final ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane();
        root.setFitToWidth(true);

        Label lbl = new Label(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, "
                + "sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore "
                + "magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et "
                + "accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.");
        lbl.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
        lbl.setWrapText(true);

        AnchorPane ap = new AnchorPane();
        ap.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
        ap.getChildren().add(lbl);

        lbl.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
        lbl.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        VBox vBox = new VBox(ap);
        AnchorPane rootAP = new AnchorPane(vBox);
        root.setContent(rootAP);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        lbl.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());//This should bind the Label width to the Scene width

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 Problems with the solution: 1) The text is centered vertically in the window, I need it aligned to the top. 2) I need some layout element that allows using multiple labels (or more exactly multiple Label/AnchorPane packages) on one page